# Generic Object obtaining null value rather than a double value

Tags: java, arrays, generics, priority-queue

So the purpose of this code is to make a Priority Queue using a Sorted Array.

Currently I have a C object which returns null, when I don't believe it should be.

Relevant code:

```
    int n = 5;
    PQ<Double> pq1 = new PQasSortedArray<Double>(n); 
    double[] arr1 = new double[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Random num = new Random(); //Assigning random double values to the array
        arr1[i] = num.nextDouble();
    }

    for (int i=0; i < arr1.length; i++){
        pq1.insert(arr1[i]);
    }
    for (int i=arr1.length-1; i >=0 ; i--){
        arr1[i] = pq1.deleteMin();
    }
```

In my PQasSortedArray class I have the following relevant code:

```
public class PQasSortedArray<C extends Comparable<? super C>> implements PQ<C> {
    private C[] arr; 
    private int currentSize;

public PQasSortedArray(int size) {
        arr = (C[]) new Comparable[size];
        currentSize = 0;
    }
public void insert(C data){ 
        arr[currentSize++] = data;
    }

public C min(){
    C tmp = arr[0]; // <-- This gives tmp a value of null, which is not what I want

    for(int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++) { // <-- This is skipped entirely as tmp is null
        if(tmp.compareTo(arr[i]) > 0) {
            tmp = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return tmp;

}

public C deleteMin(){ // <-- This also doesn't work as intended
    C tmp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[currentSize-1];
    arr[currentSize-1] = null;
    currentSize--;
    return tmp;
}
```

So I'm generally pretty unsure how to go about this. I'm not used to using generics so I could be missing something completely obvious.

```
public interface PQ<C extends Comparable<? super C>> {
public boolean isFull();

public boolean isEmpty();

public void insert(C data); 

public C min();

public C deleteMin();
```

}

Comment: The code listed in the first block is what I've been using as a test. Given 5 double values, the output is 5 double values with their indexes changed by -1, so 0 becomes the last of the array and 1 becomes 0, etc. It's supposed to delete the minimum value of the array, and return an array of size n-1 where the original array is size n. I've figured out part of what I wanted to do was order the array from least-greatest in the insert method, but I'm still confused why tmp becomes null.

Comment: "This is skipped entirely as tmp is null" there's nothing in that line that would skip if tmp was null. If currentSize was zero however...

Comment: Please post your PQ interface.

Comment: I've added the interface to the bottom of the post now.

Comment: Declaring `Random num = new Random();` inside the loop is an error. Declare it once and let it generate the pseudorandom sequence, instead of over and over and starting the sequence at the beginning each time.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the test currentSize == 1:

```
public C deleteFirst() { // <-- This also doesn't work as intended
    C tmp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[currentSize - 1];
    arr[currentSize - 1] = null;
    currentSize--;
    return tmp;
}
```

becomes:

```
public C deleteFirst() { // <-- This also doesn't work as intended
    C tmp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[0];
    arr[0] = null;
    currentSize--;
    return tmp;
}
```

Finaly: arr[0] == null and currentSize == 0.

tmp = arr[0] == null:

```
public C min(){
    C tmp = arr[0]; // <-- This gives tmp a value of null, which is not what I want

    for(int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++) { // <-- This is skipped entirely as tmp is null
        if(tmp.compareTo(arr[i]) > 0) {
            tmp = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return tmp;

}
```

You need something like this:

```
public C min() {
    if (currentSize == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Size is 0.");
    }

    C tmp = arr[0]; // <-- This gives tmp a value of null, which is not what I want

    for (int i = 1; i < currentSize; i++) { // <-- This is skipped entirely as tmp is null
        if (tmp.compareTo(arr[i]) > 0) {
            tmp = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return tmp;

}
```